# Pandas decrease column values linearly by range

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
values = pd.DataFrame(data={'val1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']},
                     index=pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

|  | val1 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 3 | D |
| 4 | E |

How do I write a function so that given two numbers, I can add a new column that populates numbers equally between those numbers?

For example, given numbers `200` and `100`, I would have a new column `number` like the following:

|  | val1 | number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 200 |
| 1 | B | 175 |
| 2 | C | 150 |
| 3 | D | 125 |
| 4 | E | 100 |

Answer (score 2):

Let's use `np.linspace`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_values = pd.DataFrame(data={'val1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']},
                     index=pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))

df_values['number'] = np.linspace(200, 100, df_values.shape[0])
df_values
```

Output:

```
  val1  number
0    A   200.0
1    B   175.0
2    C   150.0
3    D   125.0
4    E   100.0
```